# Excel - Get Value from 'Column A' Based on MAX of 'Column L'

Tags: excel, max, vlookup

I have values in column L which are the number of calls an agent has made. The agents name is in column A.

I am trying to get the max value from column L and display the name of that agent.

Here's an example of my data:

```
 Column A  |  Column B |  Column C | ... | Column L
Agent Name | 25-Mar-17 | 26-Mar-17 | ... |  Totals
---------------------------------------------------
   Kelly         5           9       ...      14
  Bryson         7           4       ...      11
 Brittany        3          14       ...      17
```

I would want the calculation to display `Brittany`, as she has the highest total.

Comment: Are you using a script to query the data? What language? Or are you using .Net to query the excel worksheet? Can you use LINQ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(L:L),L:L,0))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this with so many different combinations, argh! Thank you, it works.

Comment: @WolfieeifloW please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.